# Transit Visa for going out of Istanbul Airport travelling by Turkish Airlines

Tags: transit, transit-visas, istanbul, turkish-airlines

I'm a citizen of Bangladesh holding Bangladeshi Passport. I have a residence permit for both Finland and Sweden. I'll be traveling to Stockholm by Turkish Airlines which has a layover in Istanbul Airport. Do I need to take a visa to go outside of the airport for a short city tour?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need a visa. You can apply for it [online here](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).